# Cast Exception while adding new toolbar icon inside a content page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While adding a new tool bar item on my content page toolbar icon it is throwing an exception:

> > **System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
> >       at Xamarin.Forms.ButtonElement.OnCommandChanging (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bo, System.Object o, System.Object n)**

Here is my code for adding new toolbar item:

```
ToolbarItem deleteItem = new ToolbarItem();
deleteItem.Icon = "DeleteIcon";
deleteItem.Text = "Delete";
deleteItem.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Default;
deleteItem.Priority = 1;
deleteItem.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("DeleteTransaction"));
this.CurrentPage.ToolbarItems.Add(deleteItem); //error throwing on this line
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the cast for the command, check this example. It is `MenuItem.CommandProperty`

```
  var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem();
            toolbarItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, new Binding("ActionBarButtonCommand"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this over time that when you add text and icon to a single `ToolbarItem` it throws some kind of a cast exception.

I do not remember if this is the same issue but I would suggest you remove `deleteItem.Text = "Delete";` and see if that works or not.